How to fill a complex shape to make it printable
I'm new to blender and can't find a solution to my problem anywhere.
I have created a simple low poly model by connecting vertices to faces (using F).
Now I want to fill my model so I can print it.
I can't figure out how to do it expect selecting each face manually and extruding it.
What I have tried so far:

selecting all faces and extruding (deforms the whole thing)
using Modifier > solidify (only make it thicker but no way to say I just want to solidify towards -Z)

Is there an easy way to do this?

Thanks in advance for the help!

If your object has intersecting faces it won't work, you can activate the addon called Mesh: 3D-Print Toolbox and press the Check All button in the N panel > 3D-Print. If the topology is not correct you can try to remesh it with the inner remesh tools of Blender, or with a software like Instant Meshes but it may not work well, or the shape may not be as sharp as you want. In that case you need to rework with a clean topology from the start

It appears that this shape has a considerable number of intersecting faces. Addressing this issue may be challenging for someone new to Blender. I suggest starting with some basic modeling tutorials in Blender to gain a better understanding of modeling techniques. So I'm voting to close this question as needing more focus on a specific problem.

You could apply solidify modifier, select all faces you want to be the bottom and scale them to 0 in some axis(Z most likely)to make them flat. There are good reasons to hate overlapping geometry, but 3d printing slicers cope with it well(not in all cases, obviously) so you could try to slice it. It may be OK if you don't have inverted normals. You will probably have to fix all the parts that have holes manually. That does not however make the forms printable. As this seems to be quite a mess, it's hard to say if you are going to have problems printing it or not.
